# a problem regarding centre of similitude

Tags: geometry

In the book  [Roger A. Johnson, *Advanced Euclidean Geometry*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=559e2AVvrvYC&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=from+a+point+of+intersection+of+two+circles+the+lines+to+the+centre+of+similitude+bisect+the+angle+between+the+radii+of+the+circles&source=bl&ots=ThBp3FIgn5&sig=ACfU3U3-rwH0nME3YlfJKnLCX-glmoRfxw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKg_Tx16LiAhV68HMBHVxyD9oQ6AEwB3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=from%20a%20point%20of%20intersection%20of%20two%20circles%20the%20lines%20to%20the%20centre%20of%20similitude%20bisect%20the%20angle%20between%20the%20radii%20of%20the%20circles&f=false)  on page no. 19 there is a theorem

> from a point of intersection of two circles the lines to the centre of similitude bisect the angle between the radii of the circles.

I am not getting what is the angle between the radii of the two circles.

Please draw the figure for this theorem

I shall be very thankfull.

Comment: In the text in the link provided, it says *centers* of similitude; I'm not sure how we can have more than one center of similitude when the 2 circles are intersecting. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: @ExtremeRaider: Draw two parallel radii in different directions. Connect points where radii intersect the circles. The intersection of this line with the line connecting centers will be internal center (this center will be between the centers of the circles). Now draw two radii in the same direction and again, connect points of intersection. This time, the line will intersect line that connect centers outside of the segment that connect centers. This is the external center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the illustration of the theorem (actually a corollary in the referenced book). Here $H$ is the internal center of similitude, $H_1$ is the external one, the theorem states that $IH$ bisects $\angle AIC$:[image]

Comment: That made it a lot more clear, thanks! If you don't mind me asking, Which software did you use to make this illustration?

Comment: @ExtremeRaider: I used https://www.geogebra.org/